# Remove element from list if part of string is duplicate

Tags: python, string, list

What I want to do is to remove string elements from my list that have some duplicate parts. For example, if I have given list.

```
ls = ['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004', '02/27', '07/21', '08/13']
```

I want output as

```
ls_out = ['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004']
```

That is `'02/27'` already existed in `'02/27/1960'`.

(**note** that I'm not sure if this question is duplicated or not)

Comment: Do you only need this to work with dates in that format, or arbitrary strings?

Comment: Hello @Max Feng, right now, I would like to do in this given format. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be solve with a `for` loop and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any) built-in method:

```
>>> ls
['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004', '02/27', '07/21', '08/13']
>>>
>>> ls_out = []
>>> 
>>> for x in ls:
        if not any([x in item for item in ls_out]):
            ls_out.append(x)


>>> ls_out
['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004']
```

OR:

```
>>> for x in ls:
        if all([x not in item for item in ls_out]):
            ls_out.append(x)


>>> ls_out
['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004']
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Iron Fist, this works really well for me!

Comment: @titipat .. no pblm .. ;)

Comment: Generator comprehension rather than list comprehension with the `any` approach seems like it would be the most efficient. Also, to me it seems like checking  `x not in ls_out` is overkill. Better to just use: `if not any(x in item for item in ls_out):`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga...correct...it seems redundant as the second condition is a factor for both ...Good observation .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this, but it would definitely work:

```
ls = ['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004', '02/27', '07/21', '08/13']

ls2 = ls

for item in ls:
  for dup_item in ls2:
    if item == dup_item:
      continue
    if item.startswith(dup_item):
      _ = ls.pop(ls.index(dup_item))

print ls
```

Basically, it creates two identical lists, loops through both and checks if they're equal - if they are, it skips. If they aren't, it checks if they start with the other one. If it does, it removes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
cache = set()
def fun(s):
    ss = s.split('/')
    key = ss[0] + '/' + ss[1]
    if key in cache:
        return None
    else:
        cache.add(key)
        return s

ls = ['02/27/1960', '07/21/2004', '08/13/2004', '09/12/2004', '02/27', '07/21', '08/13']

new_ls = filter(fun, ls)
print new_ls
```

Comment: It makes more sense to use a set as a cache rather than a dictionary with a useless mapping.

Comment: First, thanks @atline! @juanpa.arrivillaga I see. So, I have to change `cache` to empty set and check if `key` is in `cache`, I guess.

Comment: How about above? Seems set really better than hash.

Comment: Yeah, I did use solution above. However, thanks so much @atline :)